# Confused by Prometheus 'elements': there seem to be three per pod?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, prometheus, kubernetes-pod

**Situation:** I just set up Prometheus for my Kubernetes cluster, and wanted to take a closer look at resource usage. Seemed like the way to do this was with `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`, but I'm confused by the results.

**Problem:** Prometheus seems to be returning three different elements for each (single-container) pod. I don't know what these different elements represent, and haven't been able to find a clear explanation on Google.

---

**What I'm doing:**

I'm executing this query, where MY-POD-IDENTIFIER is the name of a Kubernetes Pod with one defined container:

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="MY-POD-IDENTIFIER"}[5m])
```

**What I'm seeing:**

The `console` tab gives me a table of (element, value) with three entries, as seen in the image below. I've included a simplified list of the returned elements below.

[image]

```
[
{
    beta_kubernetes_io_arch = "amd64",
    beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type = "m5a.xlarge",
    beta_kubernetes_io_os = "linux",
    container = "POD",
    cpu = "total",
    id = "/kubepods/podSOME-LONG-ID/A-LONG-ID",
    image = "602401143452.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/eks/pause-amd64:3.1",
    instance = "MY-INTERNAL-NODE-INSTANCE",
    job = "kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor",
    name = "k8s_POD_MY-POD-IDENTIFIER-WITH-LONGID",
    namespace = "staging",
    pod = "MY-POD-IDENTIFIER"
},
{
    beta_kubernetes_io_arch = "amd64",
    beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type = "m5a.xlarge",
    beta_kubernetes_io_os = "linux",
    container = "MY-CONTAINER-IMAGE-NAME",
    cpu = "total",
    id = "/kubepods/podSOME-LONG-ID/A-DIFFERENT-LONG-ID",
    image = "111111111.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/MY-KUBERNETES-CONTAINER-IMAGE",
    instance = "MY-INTERNAL-NODE-INSTANCE",
    job = "kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor",
    name = "k8s_MY-POD-NAME_MY-POD-IDENTIFIER-WITH-LONGID",
    namespace = "staging",
    pod = "MY-POD-IDENTIFIER"
},
{
    beta_kubernetes_io_arch = "amd64",
    beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type = "m5a.xlarge",
    beta_kubernetes_io_os = "linux",
    cpu = "total",
    id = "/kubepods/podSOME-LONG-ID",
    instance = "MY-INTERNAL-NODE-INSTANCE",
    job = "kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor",
    namespace = "staging",
    pod = "MY-POD-IDENTIFIER"
}]
```

The `graph` tab gives me this view:
[image]

These lines match up to the previous list of elements:

1. First element: red
2. Second element: light green
3. Third element: dark green

---

**My Guesses:**

Looking at the list of elements, one of the differentiating factors seems to be the `container` value. This is respectively: [`POD`, `MY-CONTAINER-IMAGE-NAME`, `None`]. The `POD` element has CPU usage of 0 throughout, while the other elements have similar-but-varying CPU usage of 0.6m.

My *guess* was that the `POD` element represents a kubernetes helper container within the Pod, the `MY-CONTAINER-IMAGE-NAME` element represents the container I defined, and the `None` element is a wrapper for both of those. This seems likely because of how closely the `None` element tracks the `MY-CONTAINER-IMAGE-NAME` element. But on the other hand, there is variation between them. So I'm not sure.

**My Question:**

Can someone please explain what these different Prometheus elements are? Or point me in the direction of a good resource?

Answer (score 1):

The "elements" that you see are the "targets" that Prometheus has discovered.  To fully understand how/what this is, the [Prometheus Kubernetes Service Discovery docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config) are gonna be the most helpful.

Basically (without seeing your prom config to verify which one), Prometheus is finding 3x targets per pod per some of the rules you see on that page.  E.g. with [`pods`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#pod) it will find 1 target per exposed port.

After you've figured out which of these you want and which you don't need, you can use the [`relabel_configs`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) to drop the targets that are extra and you don't need to scrape.